# Node Modules installation failing

Tags: angular, npm

I am getting the below error when I do npm install in an Angular Project

```
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/core@"13.3.8" from @angular/router@13.3.8
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/router
npm WARN   @angular/router@"13.3.8" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: angular-user-idle@2.2.7
npm WARN Found: @angular/core@13.3.8
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/core
npm WARN   @angular/core@"13.3.8" from the root project
npm WARN   7 more (@angular/animations, @angular/cdk, @angular/forms, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/core@"^6.0.0 || ^12.0.0" from angular-user-idle@2.2.7
npm WARN node_modules/angular-user-idle
npm WARN   angular-user-idle@"^2.2.7" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: angular-user-idle@2.2.7
npm WARN Found: @angular/core@13.3.8
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/core
npm WARN   @angular/core@"13.3.8" from the root project
npm WARN   7 more (@angular/animations, @angular/cdk, @angular/forms, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/core@"^6.1.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0" from apollo-angular@2.6.0
npm WARN node_modules/apollo-angular
npm WARN   apollo-angular@"^2.6.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: angular-user-idle@2.2.7
npm WARN Found: @angular/core@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/core
npm WARN   @angular/core@"13.3.8" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/core@"^6.0.0 || ^12.0.0" from angular-user-idle@2.2.7
npm WARN node_modules/angular-user-idle
npm WARN   angular-user-idle@"^2.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://jfrog.aws.domain.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/ajv failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND jfrog.aws.wfscorp.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2022-06-17T18_56_28_331Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal write

```
sudo npm install
```

Comment: tried that same error even tried npm install --legacy -peer -deps

Answer (score 0):

This error is reporting that some of your dependencies are not compatible with angular 13+

- angular-user-idle@2.2.7
- apollo-angular@^2.6.0

need to upgrade them to versions compatible with angular 13.

These should do it, looking at their repos, update your `package.json` file for these two:

- [angular-user-idle](https://github.com/rednez/angular-user-idle): "^3.0.0"
- [apollo-angular](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular): "^3.0.0"

And run `npm install` again.

You might have to do some upgrading on your usage of those two dependencies, but at least the npm error will be gone.